# SQL Server transform xml and parse single values but not with build-in functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to parse and transform XML values in SQL Server 2016. I can not use the the `sp_xml_preparedocument` or `sp_xml_removedocument` built-in procedures because I want to have it in a table value function.

I would like to select these 4 *values*:

- testXML...821327282
- Test value
- Test attribute
- Test property

XML template value:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<stns1:testXML...821327282 xmlns:stns1="qaTESTXML">
   <myvalue>Test value</myvalue>
   <myattribute>Test attribute</myattribute>
   <myproperty>Test property</myproperty>
</stns1:testXML...821327282>
```

My T-SQL try > code:

```sql
select
    [xml].[node].query('local-name(/ROOT[0]/id)') as [id],
    [xml].[node].query('local-name(/ROOT[0]/myvalue)') as [value],
    [xml].[node].query('local-name(/ROOT[0]/myattribute)') as [attribute],
    [xml].[node].query('local-name(/ROOT[0]/myproperty)') as [property]
from 
    @xml.nodes('/') as [xml]([node])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<stns1:testXML...821327282 xmlns:stns1="qaTESTXML">
   <myvalue>Test value</myvalue>
   <myattribute>Test attribute</myattribute>
   <myproperty>Test property</myproperty>
</stns1:testXML...821327282>'

-- you need to **include** and respect the XML namespace in your XML document!    
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('qaTESTXML' AS ns1)
SELECT
    [node].value('(myvalue)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [value],
    [node].value('(myattribute)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [attribute],
    [node].value('(myproperty)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [property]
FROM   
    @xml.nodes('/ns1:testXML...821327282') as [xml]([node])
```

Not sure what you mean by *selecting the `testXML...821327282` value* - that's a XML element / node - not a value.....

**Update:** if you need to get the "name" of the root node element - you can use this - **BE AWARE** that using the `//myvalue` approach is **very bad** for query performance - especially on larger XML documents! You've been warned!

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('qaTESTXML' AS ns1)
SELECT
    [node].value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as rootnode,
    [node].value('(//myvalue)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [value],
    [node].value('(//myattribute)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [attribute],
    [node].value('(//myproperty)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [property]
FROM   
    @xml.nodes('/ns1:*') as [xml]([node])
```

Comment: *"Not sure what you mean by selecting the `testXML...821327282` value"* *Perhaps* they also want the literal string value `'testXML...821327282'` as the first result in their result set? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hello Marc_s, Hello Larnu, thanks for this code fragment. Is it possible to parse aswell this testXML...821327282 string literal aswell?? Because this is the number i would need in my dataset aswell. The rest looks pretty good for me.

Comment: @Mario: ok, if it's just a few lines (like in the sample), the performance hit will not be noticeable - enjoy !